# If the text is shaded I want to change the text color to red and cancel the shadow

Tags: vba, ms-word, highlight

msWord: I want to change the text color of shadowed texts to red and remove the shadow.

I wrote the code below. Makes the shaded text color red. But I couldn't remove the shadow and the code doesn't stop, system crashes. Thank you for your help.

```
Sub Make_Highlighted_Text_Red()
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = ""
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Highlight = True
    Do
        .Execute
        Selection.Range.Font.ColorIndex = 6
    Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Get rid of the do and loop, you need to use wdreplaceall to do the replace on every found instance.

Comment: I would replace with a character style of a red text rather than directly formatting. Direct formatting adds far greater complexity to a document file than does style-based formatting. Here is my writing on this with some examples: https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Overview    Here is an article showing vba that creates a character style with a language attribute. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/creating-no-proofing-styles-in-microsoft-word-no/999c8de4-dac2-4fac-be07-ab55e8d636cc

Comment: There is an argument for not doing that for highlighting.  Bold italic and underlining can be seen as part of presenting the story, i.e. part of the layout.  Highlighting has a different semantic meaning, i.e. it is extracting metadata from the document and is not part of the layout.  I appreciate that historically bold, italics and underlining may have been used for the same reason as highlighting, but I hope you can appreciate the point I'm making.  Its a stylistic issue which is the authors choice.

Comment: Thank you @Charles Kenyon . The article and your article were instructive.

Comment: Got it, @freeflow
  I should have written more clearly. My purpose for highlighting was Text Hightilght Color.

Comment: You can use Shading instead of highlighting, if you want. Freeflow points out that conceptually (and in vba) this is different from highlighting.

Comment: Thanks @Charles Kenyon
 I couldn't find the appropriate word for emphasis. Shading is a good idea. This is how I updated my question.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a document with the formatting you are trying to fix, preferably with a sample of what you would like it to look like after it is fixed. This should be saved on a cloud service like Dropbox or OneDrive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I solved my problem with the codes below.

```
      Sub No_Shadow_Font_Color()
      Dim fndColor As String
      Dim rplcColor As String
      Dim myDoc As Document
      Dim myRng As Range
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Set myDoc = ActiveDocument
      fndColor = wdRed 'Attention Please write the shadow color you want to change here
      rplcColor = wdAuto
      With Selection
        .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        With Selection.Find
          .Highlight = True
          Do While .Execute
            If Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = fndColor Then
              Set myRng = Selection.Range
              myRng.HighlightColorIndex = rplcColor
              myRng.Font.ColorIndex = 6
              Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
            End If
          Loop
        End With
      End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set myDoc = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: `fndColor` and `rplcColor` are both incorrectly declared as `String`. As these variables are being used to hold colors they should be declared as `Long`

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I thought of `wdRed`  as string. I didn't realize it when I solved my problem as string.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).